# JedisClusterStringCommands.get(...) 67 line throw java.lang.ClassCastException by chance

Tags: classcastexception, spring-data-redis

In the case of high concurrency and frequent reads of the same key，JedisClusterStringCommands.get(...) 67 line throw java.lang.ClassCastException，it's an accidental event.

spring-data-redis version:2.5.12

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException:Unknown redis exception; nest exception is java.lang.ClassCastException

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.